# Parameters, localparams and left padding single bit-value ('1)

Tags: parameters, system-verilog

If i have understood things [correctly](https://bradpierce.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/a-verilog-parameter-infers-its-type-from-its-value-the-myth-that-there-is-a-default-signed-integer-parameter-type-in-verilog/) a SystemVerilog parameter does not have an inherent type, but will take type of the value assigned to it. Similarly the '1 notation should adapt to the type of the variable. What happens when we combine the two?

That is, what result is expected from the parameter instantiations in these snippets?

```
localparam BAR = '1;
```

and

```
module testModule #(parameter BAR = 0, parameter [3:0] LONGBAR = 0)
(input logic a, output logic b);
  assign b = a;
endmodule

testModule #('1, '1) u_testModule0(a, b);
```

and

```
testModule #(BAR, BAR) u_testModule1(a, b);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the absence of any type context (self-determined), the literal `'1` is equivalent to `1'b1`. The assignment to the `localparam BAR` is self-determined, so `BAR` is a one bit parameter with the value `1'b1`

Because your `testModule` defines `BAR` without a type, any expression used to override it will be evaluated in a self-determined context. The expression used to override `LONGBAR` will be evaluated in the context of a 4-bit integral type.

```
testModule #('1, '1) u_testModule0(a, b);
```

So in the instantiation above, the first override evaluates to `1'b1` and the second override evaluates to 4'b1111. testModule's `BAR` type resolves to a 1-bit type and LONGBAR's type is fixed at 4-bits.

```
testModule #(BAR, BAR) u_testModule1(a, b);
```

In the second instantiation, the first override takes on the type of the localparam BAR, so testModule's `BAR` type resolves to a 1-bit type with the value `1'b1`. But in the second override, this is an assignment in the context of a 4-bit type. Since localparam `BAR` has the value 1'b1, it gets padded with 0's and LONGBAR gets the value 4'b0001.

Comment: "The expression used to override LONGBAR will be evaluated in the context of a 4-bit integral type." 
How/where is this stated in the LRM? I am having issues with synthesis interpreting an instantiation like this as 4'b0001.

Comment: It is explained in Section _23.10 Overriding module parameters_ with the paragraph that says _A value parameter with a range specification, but with no type specification, shall have the range of the parameter declaration and shall be unsigned. An override value shall be converted to the type and range of the parameter_